# Displaying other webpage using cURL request

Tags: php, curl

I want to display other webpages on the website using cURL. I am not working with iframes because they do not work in a lot of cases.

I can make the pages to display using cURL using the following code.

```
    $result=query("SELECT url FROM links WHERE l_id='$linkId'");

$url =$result[0]["url"];
$ch = curl_init();

// set a single option...
// ... or an array of options
curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

));

// execute
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

But in most of the url's sometime the css file or other images do not load.

I get a 403 forbidden error. What can i do to make these errors go away in most of the cases.

I am opening a host of URL's. Again don't want to open it in a iframe. Or is there another method I could use.

Comment: I tried your code with your backlino.com URL and I got the website rather than a 403 error. It could be that you're IP has been blacklisted for too many attempts

Comment: You're trying to scrape the content from web sites and they're sending you messages saying they don't want you to do that. Take the hint.

Comment: @JamieBicknell how do u do that from user's website?

Comment: Guys first of all i am developing a authentic service, i want to enable users to annotate the article once i get it back, so if you have any other suggestion regarding how i can do this let me know. @JamieBicknell . I get the website but some images are missing, You can see the console, some elements are missing, and all of them have absolute paths.

Comment: I never implied anything, just provided an example as to why you'd be receiving 403's

Answer (score 0):

they have used related path for css and images. So you could add domain URL with  the image url.

```
Example,

 <img src="http://backlinko.com/img1.jpg"/>
 Like this.
 <img src="<?php echo $url;?>/img1.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks selvan for the reply but the images for which i am getting a 403 error already have a absolute path http://backlinko.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/viral-marketing-case-study-image.png

Answer (score 0):

The website in your example appears to have a HTACCESS rule to prevent hotlinking, this is done by the website checking the referrer.

You can add a CURL option to spoof the referrer like so:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://backlinko.com/');
```

Comment: I tried this solution but still get a lot of 403 errors for images in the wpcontent folder. Can i make any other changed to my cURL request

Comment: Can you give specific examples? I've tried the example image URL you've provided in the other comment and it's working. I can only assume my original comment is the most likely and that your IP has been blacklisted for too many requests.

Comment: I cant be blacklisted, I have made not more than 20 requests on this URL. And without the cURL the page opens perfectly. Here are some of the errors i am getting in my console for example, http://backlinko.com/wp-content/themes/backlinko/library/images/backlinko.png ,  http://backlinko.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/viral-marketing-case-study-image.png . Your console has no errors?

Comment: Have you tried setting the user agent to a generic browser like Chrome?

Comment: You may not be blacklisted, but you could be getting rate limited. The reason I suspect this is the case is because I have no trouble in fetching all of your example URLs via my console's CURL and PHP's CURL. So the only difference between my requests and your requests are the IP address.

Comment: Yes i have set the user agent to a generic browser, can you share the cURL request you are using

Comment: It's exactly the same as your code example in your question.